# Java - SimpleDateFormat - ParseException - Pattern seems to match

Tags: java

I wrote a class that tries to convert objects to dates.

For string representations, it tries to determine the date format by searching for a match of a predefined date format pattern against that string. If a pattern matches, it uses that pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` to parse that string to date.

I know that this approach is not deterministic as it will fail on, for example, 8/6/1928, where multiple patterns like d/M/yyyy and M/d/yyyy would match.

What follows is the relevant code section that throws a ParseException:

```
// dateFormat is "d MMMM yyyy"

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);


// objectToConvert is "8 June 1982"
return simpleDateFormat.parse((String)objectToConvert);
```

I do not understand why I get the following ParseException:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "8 June 1982"
```

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: Interestingly, this works for me in Java 6.

Comment: Dear Aleksandr, you are right. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you are in a different `Locale` where the month of June is spelt differently (for me, in my locale, it is `Juni`).

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. The server where my code runs is in a different `Locale`.I changed the parameters of my date parser so that the caller can optionally pass a `Locale`.